# MS Flow - Format Approval Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, ms-flow

How can I format **Email body** using Approval action in SharePoint Online using MS Flow?

I have used markdown but some formatting is not working.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approval action in MS Flow currently supports only Markdown formatting. HTML formatting is not supported currently. You can check [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/approvals-markdown-support) documentation on how to use markdown language. Currently, this is the only way to format. Wait for updates from Microsoft to add html formatting to this action.

If you really want HTML formatting, then I would suggest you to write a custom flow for your approval process and use send email with options action where you will be able to format as you like.

Answer (score 0):

HTML formatting is not supported for Approval, so if you really need this I suggest:

1. use the action "Create an approval"
2. send a custom email with "Send an Email" action and add the link to approval task using the "Respond link" property of Create an Approval
3. wait for the approval using "Wait for an approval", using the Approval ID